How can I find the contour of a filled option in answer sheet?
I want to find the contour of an option circle which is filled by pencil, just like the ones in the picture, but findContours() can't work well. It is always finding the wrong contour or just even can't find it.
The picture I want to deal with:

I tried findContours(). I'm not familiar with opencv, that was the only way I know. I also tried HoughCircles but it couldn't work well as well.
I need a solution to find the countour.
Here is my code:
void CorrectPerspective(const cv::Mat& InputArray, cv::Mat& OutputArray, const std::vector<cv::Point2f>& InputPoints) {
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> xSorted = InputPoints;
    std::sort(
        xSorted.begin(),
        xSorted.end(),
        [](const cv::Point2f& a, const cv::Point2f& b) {return a.x < b.x; }
    );
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> left(xSorted.begin(), xSorted.begin() + 2);
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> right(xSorted.begin() + 2, xSorted.end());
    std::sort(
        left.begin(),
        left.end(),
        [](const cv::Point2f& a, const cv::Point2f& b) {return a.y < b.y; }
    );
    cv::Point2f topLeft = left[0];
    cv::Point2f bottomLeft = left[1];
    std::vector<float> distance;
    for (const auto& point : right) {
        distance.push_back(cv::norm(topLeft - point));
    }
    cv::Point2f topRight = right[distance[0] < distance[1] ? 0 : 1];
    cv::Point2f bottomRight = right[distance[0] < distance[1] ? 1 : 0];
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> sourceVertex = {
        topLeft,
        topRight,
        bottomRight,
        bottomLeft
    };
    float widthA = std::sqrt(std::pow(bottomRight.x - bottomLeft.x, 2) + std::pow(bottomRight.y - bottomLeft.y, 2));
    float widthB = std::sqrt(std::pow(topRight.x - topLeft.x, 2) + std::pow(topRight.y - topLeft.y, 2));
    int width = static_cast<int>(std::max(widthA, widthB));
    float heightA = std::sqrt(std::pow(topRight.x - bottomRight.x, 2) + std::pow(topRight.y - bottomRight.y, 2));
    float heightB = std::sqrt(std::pow(topLeft.x - bottomLeft.x, 2) + std::pow(topLeft.y - bottomLeft.y, 2));
    int height = static_cast<int>(std::max(heightA, heightB));
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> targetVertex = {
        cv::Point2f(0, 0),
        cv::Point2f(width - 1, 0),
        cv::Point2f(width - 1, height - 1),
        cv::Point2f(0, height - 1)
    };
    cv::Mat transformMatrix = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(sourceVertex, targetVertex);
    cv::warpPerspective(InputArray, OutputArray, transformMatrix, cv::Size(width, height));
}

void PreProcess(const cv::Mat& InputArray, cv::Mat& OutputArray1, cv::Mat& OutputArray2) {
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(
        InputArray,
        gray,
        cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY
    );
    cv::Mat gaussianBlurred;
    cv::GaussianBlur(
        gray,
        gaussianBlurred,
        cv::Size(5, 5),
        0
    );
    cv::Mat edged;
    cv::Canny(
        gaussianBlurred,
        edged,
        50,
        200
    );
    OutputArray1 = edged.clone();
    cv::threshold(
        gaussianBlurred,
        OutputArray2,
        0,
        255,
        cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv::THRESH_OTSU);
}

int main() {
    cv::Mat img;
    img = cv::imread("I:\\ProjectArtemis\\OpenCVTest1\\testimg.png");


    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::Mat edged;
    cv::Mat thresh;
    PreProcess(img, edged, thresh);
    cv::findContours(
        edged.clone(),
        contours,
        hierarchy,
        cv::RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    );


    cv::Mat warped;
    cv::Mat warped_thresh;
    for (const auto& c : contours) {
        double peri = 0.01 * cv::arcLength(c, true);
        std::vector<cv::Point> approx;
        cv::approxPolyDP(c, approx, peri, true);

        if (approx.size() == 4) {
            std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
            for (const auto& point : approx) {
                points.push_back(cv::Point2f(point.x, point.y));
            }
            CorrectPerspective(img, warped, points);
            CorrectPerspective(thresh, warped_thresh, points);
        }
    }


    cv::Mat opt;
    cv::Mat opt_thresh;
    PreProcess(warped, opt, opt_thresh);    //能跑起来就先别动
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> optionContours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> optionHierarchy;
    cv::findContours(
        opt.clone(),
        optionContours,
        optionHierarchy,
        cv::RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    );


    cv::cvtColor(warped_thresh, warped_thresh, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> options;
    std::vector<cv::Rect> boundingRects;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < optionContours.size(); i++) {
        cv::Rect bounding = cv::boundingRect(optionContours[i]);
        int x = bounding.x;
        int y = bounding.y;
        int w = bounding.width;
        int h = bounding.height;

        float ar = w / static_cast<float>(h);

        if (w >= 25 && h >= 25 && ar >= 0.6 && ar <= 1.3) {
            options.push_back(optionContours[i]);
            boundingRects.push_back(bounding);
            cv::putText(warped, std::to_string(i), cv::Point(x - 1, y - 5), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            cv::putText(warped_thresh, std::to_string(i), cv::Point(x - 1, y - 5), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        }
    }


that's typical OMR. consider the sheet to be a "form" to fill in. have a template of the form. align the scan/picture to the template. sample the areas of the scan/pic given some (perhaps manually defined) area information in the template. done.

take a look at https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/03/bubble-sheet-multiple-choice-scanner-and-test-grader-using-omr-python-and-opencv/

Your question appears to be related to a learning exercise or project. Below is an other method that may help you approach the problem on alternative way
giving a result image like

if your input images has such quality i think no need to perspective correction. instead you can sort found rects and use the rects coordinates to calculate results.
void PreProcess(const cv::Mat& InputArray, cv::Mat& OutputArray1, cv::Mat& OutputArray2) {
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(
        InputArray,
        gray,
        cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY
    );
    cv::Mat gaussianBlurred;
    cv::GaussianBlur(
        gray,
        gaussianBlurred,
        cv::Size(5, 5),
        0
    );
    cv::Mat edged;
    cv::Canny(
        gaussianBlurred,
        edged,
        50,
        200
    );
    OutputArray1 = edged.clone();
    cv::threshold(
        gaussianBlurred,
        OutputArray2,
        0,
        255,
        cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv::THRESH_OTSU);
}

int main() {
    cv::Mat img;
    img = cv::imread("c:\\github\\e86ytJOv.jpg",IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2);


    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::Mat edged;
    cv::Mat thresh;
    PreProcess(img, edged, thresh);
    cv::findContours(
        edged.clone(),
        contours,
        hierarchy,
        cv::RETR_EXTERNAL,
        cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    );

    for (const auto& c : contours) {
        if (c.size() > 40)
        {
            RotatedRect rr = minAreaRect(c);
            rr.angle = 0;
            float aspect_ratio = std::max(rr.size.height, rr.size.width) / std::min(rr.size.height, rr.size.width);
            if (aspect_ratio < 1.1)
            {
            Mat mpoints1;
            boxPoints(rr, mpoints1);
            mpoints1.convertTo(mpoints1, CV_32S);
            Rect r = rr.boundingRect();
            Mat box;
            dilate(img(r), box,Mat());
            Scalar rect_mean = mean(box);

            if ((rect_mean[0]+rect_mean[1]+rect_mean[2])/3 < 140)
                rectangle(img, r, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            else
                rectangle(img, r, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
            }

        }
    }

    imshow("img", img);
    waitKey();
}

